# Erro de importação de imagens dizendo "módulo não encontrado" no React

Tags: react

Estou realizando um projeto React.ts, até então estava tudo normal, mas quando fui acessar o projeto no visual studio code recentemente está aparecendo um erro referente a importação de imagens, reclamando que "Não é possível localizar o módulo '../../assets/images/windOrange.png' ou suas declarações de tipo correspondentes.ts(2307)" sendo que o caminho da imagem está correto e está sendo renderizando no projeto. O que eu faço para esse erro sumir?

```
import garantia from '../../assets/images/garantia.png'
import set from '../../assets/images/seta.png'
import windOrange from '../../assets/images/windOrange.png'

export const SectionSeven = () => {
    return (
        <C.Section>
            <C.Container>
                <C.Img src={garantia} alt="" />
                <C.AreaText>
                    <C.Title>
                        Compre agora e tenha 7 dias para decidir se o curso é para você!
                    </C.Title>
                    <C.P>
                        É isso mesmo, se em até 7 dias você não estiver satisfeito
                        com o curso, poderá desistir da compra e ter seu reembolso!
                    </C.P>
                </C.AreaText>
            </C.Container>
            <C.AreaSet>
                <C.Wind src={windOrange} />
                <C.Set src={set} />
            </C.AreaSet>
            <C.PaddingButton>
                <C.Button>
                    Sim, eu quero começar meu negócio
                </C.Button>
            </C.PaddingButton>
        </C.Section>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Para resolver esse problema no TypeScript, você pode criar um arquivo de declaração de módulo para importações de imagens. Isso ajuda o TypeScript a entender que você está importando um arquivo de imagem e não um módulo de código.

Crie uma pasta chamada **typings** na raiz do seu projeto (se você ainda não tiver uma).

Dentro da pasta **typings**, crie um arquivo chamado **custom.d.ts** (ou qualquer nome com a extensão **.d.ts**).

Adicione esse codigo no seu arqivo com a extensão .d.ts:

```
declare module '*.png' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Por fim, certifique-se de que seu arquivo **tsconfig.json** inclua a pasta **typings** no campo include. Seu **tsconfig.json** deve ter uma seção semelhante a esta:

```
{
  "include": [
    "src",
    "typings"
  ],
  ...
}
```

> Se já existir um arquivo **.d.ts** em seu projeto, você pode adicionar o
> código referente ao **declare module** diretamente ao final desse arquivo,
> sem a necessidade de criar um novo. Isso simplifica a solução e
> permite que você estenda as declarações de tipo existentes com o
> suporte à importação de **imagens PNG**.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-na-rede?cb=1